# Bootstrap container-fluid adding scrollbar due to col and fluid css adding 15px padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap (using version v3.3.7) is adding 30px extra left/right padding to my browser padding and so adding a scrollbar when I use a fluid container. Normal bootstrap container is fine.

[edit]**If I remove the bootstrap js file, then I do not get the padding issue.**

I have read up on this and all the problems seem to step from from older versions where the following was required:

```
.container-fluid {
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

But this is exactly what my css says.

I have been able to 'fix' it by removing the same padding left/right that is also added to 'col-xs-12' css. But why, This is all I am doing?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">            
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../patientApp/css/bootstrap-theme.css" >
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
layout test
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <DIV class="col-xs-12">
                <span title="">TEST</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If I add multiple columns to add up to 12, the same thing happens.

thanks.

Comment: Which browser you are using? Because the same code i implemented in fiddle it's working fine.

Comment: can you show the real problem in the code. cause it's maybe not the bootstrap padding is the reason.

Comment: Hello, I have updated the code. Seems when I remove the bootstrap js link it stops going funny?